# UILabel in UIscrollView does not recognize UISwipegesture

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

```
code:
lblQuestion = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(23, intQuesPos, 280, 100)];
    lblQuestion.numberOfLines = 0;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *topGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeToptoBottom)];
    [topGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
    [lblQuestion addGestureRecognizer:topGesture];
    [scrollQuestion addSubview:lblQuestion];
    [vwQuestion addSubview:scrollQuestion];
```

I have `UILabel` in `UIScrollView` and I added `UISwipegesture` to `UILabel`. When I swipe down the `UISCrollView` only detected.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make userInteractionEnabled true for the lable

```
    lblQuestion.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```